# Correct implementation of the Flutter in_app_purchase plugin for multiple consumables

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I've followed [FireShip.io](https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-inapp-purchases/) tutorial on how to implement the [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) plugin as I am trying to implement purchases on consumable products in my app. I've had some success and am 95% of the way there but there is one bug I can't seem to fix.

**Expected:**
1. Purchase consumable using test card, always approves.
2. Consumables added to users app
3. Purchase consumable using test card, always declines.
4. App returns null OR pop-up saying transaction declined.

**Actual**
1. Purchase consumable using test card, always approves.
2. Consumables added to users app
3. Purchase consumable using test card, always declines.
4. Consumables added to users app (i.e. code is returning the last purchase)

Main difference between the tutorial and my implementation is he had only 1 consumable whilst my app has 4.  I've included all the code below, but I believe the problem is in this method:

```
// Returns purchase of specific product ID
  PurchaseDetails _hasPurchased(List<String> productID) {

    return _purchases.lastWhere(
        (purchase) => productID.any((String prod) => prod == purchase.productID),
        orElse: () => null);
```

His implementation of the same method:

```
  /// Returns purchase of specific product ID
  PurchaseDetails _hasPurchased(String productID) {
    return _purchases.firstWhere( (purchase) => purchase.productID == productID, orElse: () => null);
  }
```

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:find_the_treasure/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:find_the_treasure/services/database.dart';
import 'package:find_the_treasure/widgets_common/buy_diamond_key_button.dart';
import 'package:find_the_treasure/widgets_common/platform_alert_dialog.dart';
import 'package:find_the_treasure/widgets_common/quests/diamondAndKeyContainer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

// App Store and Google Play consumable IDS
const String _diamond50 = 'diamond_50';
const String _diamond150 = 'diamond_150';
const String _diamond300 = 'diamond_300';
const String _diamond500 = 'diamond_500';

class ShopScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShopScreenState createState() => _ShopScreenState();
}

class _ShopScreenState extends State<ShopScreen> {
  // IAP Plugin Interface
  final InAppPurchaseConnection _iap = InAppPurchaseConnection.instance;
  // Updates to purchases
  StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>> _subscription;

  // Products for sale
  List<ProductDetails> _products = [];
  // Past purchases
  List<PurchaseDetails> _purchases = [];
  // Is the API available on the device
  bool _isAvailable = false;
  // Diasble button if purchase pending
  bool _isPurchasePending = false;

  // Consumable credits the user can buy
  int _diamonds = 0;
  int _keys = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initialise();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _initialise() async {
    // Check availilbility of In App Purchases
    _isAvailable = await _iap.isAvailable();

    if (_isAvailable) {
      List<Future> futures = [_getProducts(), _getPastPurchases()];
      await Future.wait(futures);
      _verifyPurchase();

      // Listen to new purchases
      _subscription = _iap.purchaseUpdatedStream.listen((data) => setState(() {
            _purchases.addAll(data);

            _verifyPurchase();
          }));
    }
  }

  // Get all products available for sale
  Future<void> _getProducts() async {
    Set<String> ids =
        Set.from([_diamond50, _diamond150, _diamond300, _diamond500]);
    ProductDetailsResponse response = await _iap.queryProductDetails(ids);
    setState(() {
      _products = response.productDetails;
      _products.sort((a, b) => a.title.length.compareTo(b.title.length));
    });
  }

  // Gets past purchases
  Future<void> _getPastPurchases() async {
    QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse response = await _iap.queryPastPurchases();

    for (PurchaseDetails purchase in response.pastPurchases) {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.completePurchase(purchase);
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      _purchases = response.pastPurchases;
    });
  }

  // Returns purchase of specific product ID
  PurchaseDetails _hasPurchased(List<String> productID) {

    return _purchases.lastWhere(
        (purchase) => productID.any((String prod) => prod == purchase.productID),
        orElse: () => null);


  }

  void _verifyPurchase() async {
    DatabaseService _databaseService =
        Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context, listen: false);
    UserData _userData = Provider.of<UserData>(context, listen: false);

    PurchaseDetails purchase =
        _hasPurchased([_diamond50, _diamond150, _diamond300, _diamond500]);
    if (purchase != null && purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
      _isPurchasePending = true;
      _getCorrect(purchase);

      final _updateUserData = UserData(
          displayName: _userData.displayName,
          email: _userData.email,
          photoURL: _userData.photoURL,
          uid: _userData.uid,
          userDiamondCount: _userData.userDiamondCount + _diamonds,
          userKeyCount: _userData.userKeyCount + _keys);

      final _didSelectOK = await PlatformAlertDialog(
              title: 'Jackpot!',
              content:
                  'I\'ll add the loot to ye treasure chest. Happy adventures.',
              image: Image.asset('images/ic_thnx.png'),
              defaultActionText: 'Add Loot')
          .show(context);
      if (_didSelectOK) {
        _databaseService.updateUserDiamondAndKey(userData: _updateUserData);
        _isPurchasePending = false;
      }
    } else if (purchase != null && purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
      _isPurchasePending = true;
      PlatformAlertDialog(
              title: 'Purchase Pending',
              content:
                  'Your order is being processed, you\'ll recieve an order update very soon.',
              image: Image.asset('images/ic_credit_card.png'),
              defaultActionText: 'OK')
          .show(context);
    } else if (purchase != null && purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
      _isPurchasePending = true;
      PlatformAlertDialog(
              title: 'Shiver Me Timbers!',
              content:
                  'There has been an error whilst processing your payment. Please try again.',
              image: Image.asset('images/ic_owl_wrong.png'),
              defaultActionText: 'OK')
          .show(context);
    }

  }

  void _getCorrect(PurchaseDetails purchase) {
    switch (purchase.productID) {
      case _diamond50:
        _diamonds = 50;
        _keys = 1;
        break;
      case _diamond150:
        _diamonds = 150;
        _keys = 2;
        break;
      case _diamond300:
        _diamonds = 300;
        _keys = 3;
        break;
      case _diamond500:
        _diamonds = 500;
        _keys = 5;
        break;
    }
  }

  void _buyProduct(ProductDetails productDetails) {
    final PurchaseParam purchaseParam =
        PurchaseParam(productDetails: productDetails);
    _iap.buyConsumable(
      purchaseParam: purchaseParam,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black87),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Consumer<UserData>(
              builder: (_, _userData, __) => DiamondAndKeyContainer(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                numberOfDiamonds: _userData.userDiamondCount,
                numberOfKeys: _userData.userKeyCount,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(
                  "images/background_shop.png",
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            child: _isAvailable
                ? Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                    //  Image.asset(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.help_outline,
                        color: Colors.brown.shade300,
                        size: 40,
                      ),
                      tooltip: 'Store questions',
                      onPressed: () async {
                        final _didSelectOK = await PlatformAlertDialog(
                                title: 'Welcome to The Shop',
                                content:
                                    'Stock ye treasure chest with diamonds and keys. Use \'em to unlock quests and ye can also trade \'em for hints!',
                                image: Image.asset('images/ic_thnx.png'),
                                defaultActionText: 'OK')
                            .show(context);
                        if (_didSelectOK) {}
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    for (var prod in _products)
                      BuyDiamondOrKeyButton(
                        numberOfDiamonds: numberOfDiamonds(prod.price),
                        diamondCost: prod.price,
                        bonusKey: numberOfKeys(prod.price),
                        onPressed: () => _buyProduct(prod),
                        isPending: _isPurchasePending,
                      ),

                    // BuyTreasureChest()
                  ])
                : Center(
                    child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Loading Store...'),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Image.asset(
                          'images/compass.gif',
                          height: 200,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ))),
      ),
    );
  }

  String numberOfDiamonds(String productPrice) {
    String _numberOfDiamonds;
    switch (productPrice) {
      case '\$4.99':
        _numberOfDiamonds = '50';
        break;
      case '\$9.99':
        _numberOfDiamonds = '150';
        break;
      case '\$19.99':
        _numberOfDiamonds = '300';
        break;
      case '\$39.99':
        _numberOfDiamonds = '500';
        break;
      default:
        _numberOfDiamonds = '50';
    }
    return _numberOfDiamonds;
  }

  String numberOfKeys(String productPrice) {
    String _numberOfKeys;
    switch (productPrice) {
      case '\$4.99':
        _numberOfKeys = '1';
        break;
      case '\$9.99':
        _numberOfKeys = '2';
        break;
      case '\$19.99':
        _numberOfKeys = '3';
        break;
      case '\$39.99':
        _numberOfKeys = '5';
        break;
      default:
        _numberOfKeys = 'err';
    }
    return _numberOfKeys;
  }
}

class BuyTreasureChest extends StatelessWidget {
  const BuyTreasureChest({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
      child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, children: [
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              'images/chest.png',
              height: 40,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('? x', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25)),
            SizedBox(width: 8),
            Image.asset(
              'images/2.0x/ic_diamond.png',
              height: 20,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('? x', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25)),
            Image.asset(
              'images/skull_key_outline.png',
              height: 30,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 24),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              color: Colors.grey.shade800),
          child: Text(
            '\$9.99',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey.shade800,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.amberAccent, width: 2),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35)),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to add this:

```
InAppPurchaseConnection.completePurchase
```

Comment: Add more details because where we add this, we don't know.